# Too many arguments to function call

Tags: objective-c

I am getting this error. I'll admit that I don't know anything about using Xcode. I received this code and was told that it would work. Everything was fine aside from two errors. The specific code segments are:

```
objc_msgSend(obj, legacySelector, arguments, dict);
```

and

```
objc_msgSend(obj, normalSelector, command);
```

The full code follows:

```
#include <objc/message.h>
#import "CDV.h"
#import "CDVCommandQueue.h"
#import "CDVViewController.h"

@implementation CDVCommandQueue

@synthesize currentlyExecuting = _currentlyExecuting;

- (id)initWithViewController:(CDVViewController*)viewController
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        _viewController = viewController;
        _queue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)resetRequestId
{
    _lastCommandQueueFlushRequestId = 0;
}

- (void)enqueCommandBatch:(NSString*)batchJSON
{
    if ([batchJSON length] > 0) {
        [_queue addObject:batchJSON];
        [self executePending];
    }
}

- (void)maybeFetchCommandsFromJs:(NSNumber*)requestId
{
    // Use the request ID to determine if we've already flushed for this request.
    // This is required only because the NSURLProtocol enqueues the same request
    // multiple times.
    if ([requestId integerValue] > _lastCommandQueueFlushRequestId) {
        _lastCommandQueueFlushRequestId = [requestId integerValue];
        [self fetchCommandsFromJs];
    }
}

- (void)fetchCommandsFromJs
{
    // Grab all the queued commands from the JS side.
    NSString* queuedCommandsJSON = [_viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
        @"cordova.require('cordova/exec').nativeFetchMessages()"];

    [self enqueCommandBatch:queuedCommandsJSON];
}

- (void)executePending
{
    // Make us re-entrant-safe.
    if (_currentlyExecuting) {
        return;
    }
    @try {
        _currentlyExecuting = YES;

        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [_queue count]; ++i) {
            // Parse the returned JSON array.
            NSArray* commandBatch = [[_queue objectAtIndex:i] cdvjk_mutableObjectFromJSONString];

            // Iterate over and execute all of the commands.
            for (NSArray* jsonEntry in commandBatch) {
                CDVInvokedUrlCommand* command = [CDVInvokedUrlCommand commandFromJson:jsonEntry];
                if (![_viewController execute:command]) {
#ifdef DEBUG
                        NSString* commandJson = [jsonEntry cdvjk_JSONString];
                        static NSUInteger maxLogLength = 1024;
                        NSString* commandString = ([commandJson length] > maxLogLength) ?
                        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[...]", [commandJson substringToIndex:maxLogLength]] :
                        commandJson;

                        DLog(@"FAILED pluginJSON = %@", commandString);
#endif
                }
            }
        }

        [_queue removeAllObjects];
    } @finally
    {
        _currentlyExecuting = NO;
    }
}

- (BOOL)execute:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    if ((command.className == nil) || (command.methodName == nil)) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: Classname and/or methodName not found for command.");
        return NO;
    }

    // Fetch an instance of this class
    CDVPlugin* obj = [_viewController getCommandInstance:command.className];

    if (!([obj isKindOfClass:[CDVPlugin class]])) { // still allow deprecated class, until 1.0 release
        NSLog(@"ERROR: Plugin '%@' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist.", command.className);
        return NO;
    }
    BOOL retVal = YES;

    // Find the proper selector to call.
    NSString* methodName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:", command.methodName];
    NSString* methodNameWithDict = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:withDict:", command.methodName];
    SEL normalSelector = NSSelectorFromString(methodName);
    SEL legacySelector = NSSelectorFromString(methodNameWithDict);
    // Test for the legacy selector first in case they both exist.
    if ([obj respondsToSelector:legacySelector]) {
        NSMutableArray* arguments = nil;
        NSMutableDictionary* dict = nil;
        [command legacyArguments:&arguments andDict:&dict];
        //[obj performSelector:legacySelector withObject:arguments withObject:dict];
        objc_msgSend(obj, legacySelector, arguments, dict);
    } else if ([obj respondsToSelector:normalSelector]) {
        //[obj performSelector:normalSelector withObject:command];
        objc_msgSend(obj, normalSelector, command);
    } else {
        // There's no method to call, so throw an error.
        NSLog(@"ERROR: Method '%@' not defined in Plugin '%@'", methodName, command.className);
        retVal = NO;
    }
    return retVal;
}

@end
```

Comment: Why are you calling `obj_msgSend()` instead of using the objective c means of sending messages (which you have commented out)? Regardless, you need to post the compiler error message you're receiving in full. Since the requirements for the function your calling are variadic, `id objc_msgSend(id self, SEL op, ...)`, there's nothing wrong with the number of arguments as long as it's at least two, an object pointer and a selector (which you seem to have).

Comment: Please narrow down all of the code to just the parts relevant to the question.

Comment: While this is a dupe of the linked question, **the correct fix is not to cast `objc_msgSend()`** but to **not** use `objc_msgSend()` at all.    There is no need for it here.  Just call the methods directly using the normal method call syntax.